# Child Div floated outiside of parent

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#container{
    background:#0033FF;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}
#text{
background:#00FF00;
width:150px;
float:left;
}
#tooltip{
position:relative;
right:-100%;
background:#FF0000;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="text">Here is some text</div>
<div id="tooltip">tip</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do with the above code is to have a container div, then a div with text and then after that a div with a tooltip.  I am positining the tooltip with position relative and right:-100% so that it should appear directly to the right of the text no matter the width of the text and container.  This sort of works, however the tooltip now goes to a new line for some reason.

My question is this.  Why in the above code is the div of id tooltip on a new line?  What I would really like is for it to be on the same line.

Comment: Do not use `<!--` with it's corresponding closing tag to comment out unwanted CSS Style data because that is for HTML. Since you want to comment out CSS Styles, use `/*` and close it with `*/`  However, you can use `<!--` when it's ***prior*** to the `style` tag. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
#container{
background:#0033FF;
float:left;
width:150px;
position:relative;
}
#text{
background:#00FF00;
width:150px;
float:left;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
#tooltip{
right:0px;
top:0px;
position:absolute;
background:#FF0000;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

You can make container's position relative. And Tooltip to be positioned absolute. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Edqh8/)